# Proof of IND-q-CCA security

Tags: provable-security, chosen-ciphertext-attack, notation

I have some questions about the paper [Bounded CCA2-Secure Encryption](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rafael/papers/boundedCCA.pdf) (pdf).

On page eight "3.2 Construction", the authors have done a black-box construction of an IND-q-CCA security schema and then he says he can prove that result in 6 games (page 8 to page 10).

I do not understand the explanations of each game exactly. I lack an overview of the whole thing. I also cannot understand all the notation in the games. Could anyone explain me these games in simpler terms?